# Multiple login form with different namespace in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, namespaces, multiple-forms

I want to create two form-logins with different namespace, one for User login (namespace default "/") , one for Admin login with namespace "/admin".
When I run program, the form-login for User run fine. But form-login for Admin run fail.

This is my file spring security:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/login*" security="none" />
<http pattern="/admin/" security="none" />

<http pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern='admin/**' access='ROLE_ADMIN' />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/user/403.jsp" />
    <form-login login-page="/adminLogin" default-target-url="/adminAccess"
        authentication-failure-url="/adminLogin?error" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/adminLogin?logout" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/user/403.jsp" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/userAccess"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When I login in form-login for Admin (namespace "/admin"), The error happend with messeage "HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/admin] and action name [j_spring_security_check] associated with context path [/Java-framework]. "

The order filter in my web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Define filter for Struts 2 -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Action in my struts.xml file:

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login">  
        <result>USER_LOGIN_SPRING_SECURITY</result>  
    </action> 
    <action name="userAccess" class="springAdminAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success">USER_SPRING_SECURITY</result>
    </action>
```

```
<package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="default-web-admin">
<action name="adminAccess" class="springAdminAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success">ADMIN_SPRING_SECURITY</result>
    </action>       
<action name="adminLogin">
        <result>ADMIN_LOGIN_SPRING_SECURITY</result>  
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like the pattern `admin/**` is additive in `<http pattern="/admin/**">`.

```
<http pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern='/admin/**' access='ROLE_ADMIN' />
```

This prompt the Spring Security protected url of `/admin/admin/**` instead of `/admin/**`.

Please try following see whether it can help:

```
<http pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_ADMIN' />
```

**Edited:**

From your error:

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/admin] and
>   action name [j_spring_security_check] associated with context path
>   [/Java-framework].

the URL POST to server should be `/admin/j_spring_security_check`, but the default URL where Spring Security Form Login to trigger the authentication process is `/j_spring_security_check`.

This cause Spring Security by pass the authentication and the request of `/admin/j_spring_security_check` will pass to Struts filters and you got that error.

This URL of `j_spring_security_check` can be overridden via the `login-processing-url` attribute on `<form-login>`:

```
login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"
```

Please try this with followings:

```
<form-login login-page="/adminLogin" 
            login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check" 
            default-target-url="/adminAccess"
            authentication-failure-url="/adminLogin?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
```

**Edited2:**

From your another error,

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/admin] and
>   action name [j_spring_security_logout] associated with context path
>   [/Java-framework]

The cause is similar which the default URL for Form Logout is `j_spring_security_logout`. You can override it via `logout-url`.

Your logout filter will be look like:

```
<logout logout-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout" 
        logout-success-url="/adminLogin?logout" />
```

Comment: Yes, I think you talk true but It doesn't resolve that above error. My  problem is I can't map action of spring security with namespace "/admin".
It just works well with namespace default "/"

Comment: @joseJv If the order of filters of springSecurityFilterChain is before your struts filter in web.xml, the form action should be handled by spring security before the struts filter. If your url matched the pattern configured in spring security, it will be handled by spring security. Please check your filters in web.xml and your configuration in structs xml. If possible, please post your stack trace about spring security and it should give some hints.

Comment: I think the order filter in web.xml is true. Because, I have a form-login for User (namespace "/"). It works well. Just form-login for Admin(namespace "/admin"), it works fail
 My stack trace doesn't display special any things. It just display errors in my brower: "HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/admin] and action name [j_spring_security_check] associated with context path [/Java-framework]. "
Do you check above my struts.xml with spring security file for me?

Comment: @joseJv After check your struts and spring security xml, I think it is due to the unmatched login processing url in spring security. Please check my updated my answer see whether can help

Comment: Ok thanks you. I got it. I edited following you and I also added "/admin" into login-page, default-target-url,authencation-failure-url. Then It worked well.
Now can you tell me how to logout when admin login success. 
I try some cases such as "<logout logout-success-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout" />" or "<logout logout-success-url="/admin/adminLogin?logout" />"....
But it works failure, My browser displays error "HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/admin] and action name [j_spring_security_logout] associated with context path [/Java-framework]"

Comment: Addition, Can you tell my how to interceptor requests, I put "<intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_ADMIN,[ROLE_USER]' />" for both login-form of user and admin .
But I see it just filter requests well with user's login-form. it work wrong or not work with admin's login-form

Comment: @joseJv I updated my answer about your question for logout issue. See whether it help. About your another question, can you open a new question with your updated spring security xml and give me the link? This can help others more easier find out the answer when face the same problem :)